# RESTful GET on HTTPS returning bad request 400 error

Tags: wcf, rest, https

I recently needed to change my REST WCF service to use SSL.
It is hosted in IIS 6 and was working fine prior to the SSL requirement.

I am unable to figure out why I'm getting the 400 bad request error.
I have diagnostic logging and it says the

```
<Message>The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</Message>
```

The web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
        </webServices>
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMessageService">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
             </wsHttpBinding>
             <webHttpBinding>
                 <binding name ="webBinding">
                 </binding>
             </webHttpBinding>
             <basicHttpBinding>
                 <binding name="httpBinding">
                     <security mode="Transport">
                         <transport clientCredentialType = "None"/>
                     </security>
                 </binding>
             </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior"
                     name="XXXDataService.XXXDataService">
                <endpoint address="" 
                          binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          bindingNamespace="http://blah.blah.blah.com/XXXDataService/"
                          bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMessageService"
                          contract="ZZZDataService.IZZZDataServices">
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" 
                          binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <standardEndpoints>
            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="" 
                                  helpEnabled="true" 
                                  automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
            </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" 
                                  httpHelpPageEnabled="True"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I only removed the diagnostics part and needed to protect the names by replacing with XXX and ZZZ.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

service implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="blah.blah.blah.com", Name="XXXDataService")] 
public class YYYDataService : IYYYDataService 
{ 
    public string GetUser(string id) 
    { 
        string result = string.Empty; 
        using (YYYAdmintTree tree = new YYYAdmintTree()) // used for accessing DB 
        { 
            result = tree.GetUserById(id, 1); 
        } 
        return result; 
    }
}
```

contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="https://blah.blah.blah.com", Name="XXXDataService")]
public interface IYYYDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="/GetUser/{id}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetUserById(string id);
}
```

Comment: have you set up the binding in IIS to receive https requests?

Comment: IIS:  Require secure channel (SSL) - checked.  Ignore client certificates is selected.  When I browse to the service, svc file, it returns with the generic page and a link for the wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Error 400 comes when you pass wrong parameter as Input. If you are passing XML or JSON as an input check once again. If server was unable to locate it it would have given you error 404. But 400 indicates surely there is something wrong with input provided.

Comment: The request is made via a URL in a browser with the parameter as part of the URL - https:blah.blah.com/service/service.svc/GetUser/123

Comment: It should work just provide me the method details and the way parameters you are passing.

Comment: This is the implementation of the service:[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://blah.blah.blah.com", Name="XXXDataService")]
    public class YYYDataService : IYYYDataService
    {
        public string GetUser(string id)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            using (YYYAdmintTree tree = new YYYAdmintTree()) // used for accessing DB
            {
                result = tree.GetUserById(id, 1);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

Comment: Change `public string GetUser(string id) {` to `public string GetUser(ParamParam("id") string id) {` and pass values from Client like http://localhost:8080/whateverthespecifiedpathis/1 where 1 is the id you wish to pass. I hope you would have spefied the path properly